# How do I create dynamic elements in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to create a dynamic list of data I retrieved from a json file. My search results only got me how to create dynamic components, but I just need a list.

In JS I was able to do this with the following code.

```
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("class", "dynamicBox")
document.getElementById("target").appendChild(newDiv);
```

When I used this code in angular, I could see the div in inspector mode, but the CSS was not being applied to it. What is the correct way of dynamically creating divs / lists and other elements in angular, can anybody point me to the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: You are not following 'angular way'. You should NEVER perform operation like this in angular. You need to read more about Structural Directive and angular in general.

Comment: Use Angular's templating way - *ngIf, *ngFor, Data Binding. You know, angular.

Comment: Thank you, I am reading the Structural Directives atm and will look into templating. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *ngFor like this

```html
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div [ngClass]="item.class">{{item.data}} </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear,can you upvote and Mark as answer?

Comment: Yeah, can't upvote though, not enough points.